# jps command shows DFSAdmin process

Tags: hadoop

iam using hadoop apache 2.7.1 
on centos 7 environment

and i have an HA Cluster which consists of two name nodes(mn1 and mn2)
 and 6 data nodes

issuing jps on mn1 shows

```
34734 DFSZKFailoverController
34245 NameNode
31529 DFSAdmin
34551 JournalNode
34822 Jps
3857 QuorumPeerMain
```

and issuing jps on mn2 shows

```
26272 JournalNode
26483 Jps
26110 NameNode
26388 DFSZKFailoverController
2259 QuorumPeerMain
```

what does DFSAdmin Process in mn1 jps output refers to ?

Comment: Did you run any `dfsadmin` command on that node?

Comment: no can i kill that process without any effect

Answer (score 0):

i noticed that this dfsadmin process appeared in the following scenario:

when number of failed journal nodes exceeds possible numbers of journal nodes for cluster to continue working

Which is defined in formula 
(N-1)/ 2 where N is number of journal nodes

So the cluster will not continue to work and active name node shut downs

so if i started accepted number of journal nodes and name node again 
jps on active name node shows dfsadmin process

and this problem was solved by restarting all cluster services a gian